# How to migrate existing website from Cake PHP to Word press

Tags: wordpress, cakephp

How to migrate existing website from **Cakephp** to **Wordpress** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create new DB for WP
2. Create CakePHP command to export db data from CakePHP DB to WP DB
3. Export images to right place
4. Replace CakePHP web app with WP
5. Delete CakePHP db

Be sure what you do!!!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try that.